# change the resualts page - on "no resualt" woocomerce page

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce

Can anyone guide me trow the files that need to update in order to get

> no result found

on search redirect to other page or different text (like leading into fill form)?

I am using wp woocomerce and woof search plug in. I found on the search.php that gives me a hit.

```
        </div>
        <?php graphene_posts_nav(); ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'not-found' ); ?>
    <?php endif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to use the if else condition based on the found posts like below.

```
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                //display search template

            <?php else : ?>

               //display no results template

                <?php get_template_part( 'no-results', 'search' ); ?>

            <?php endif; ?>
```

In this case no results template will be no-results-search.php